# HTML5 Canvas drawing basic line. is it a bug?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a simple line in html5 and noticed the following problem.

The code below works great. Draws the line correctly

```
    topcanvas = document.getElementById("topborder");
topcontext = topcanvas.getContext("2d");

topcontext.clearRect(0, 0, topcanvas.width, topcanvas.height);
    topcontext.moveTo(1, 0);
    topcontext.lineTo(4,0);
    topcontext.lineWidth = 3;
topcontext.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
topcontext.stroke();
```

The code below should do the exactly same but not sure why, it draws the first line and then I dont see any change. the output is the line from (1000,0) to (4,0) where as I expect the end result to be (1,0) to (4,0)

```
    topcanvas = document.getElementById("topborder");
topcontext = topcanvas.getContext("2d");

    topcontext.clearRect(0, 0, topcanvas.width, topcanvas.height);
    topcontext.moveTo(1000, 0);
    topcontext.lineTo(4,0);
    topcontext.lineWidth = 3;
topcontext.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
topcontext.stroke();

topcontext.clearRect(0, 0, topcanvas.width, topcanvas.height);
    topcontext.moveTo(1, 0);
    topcontext.lineTo(4,0);
    topcontext.lineWidth = 3;
topcontext.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
topcontext.stroke();
```

The canvas width is 1000 and height 3

Comment: I'm sure it's a bug *somewhere* =^_^= Consider posting minimal failing case to http://jsfiddle.net (as well) so that others can see the issue (in different browsers) and easily post corrected solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear canvas do the following:

```
topcanvas.width=topcanvas.width;
```

Comment: Any explanation, as why topcanvas.width would not be the same as topcanvas.width?

Comment: It isn't, but the fact that width is assigned-to makes the underlying canvas implementation forget all the pixels it had before.  See the canvas spec:  "When the canvas element is created, and subsequently whenever the width and height attributes are set (whether to a new value or to the previous value), the bitmap and any associated contexts must be cleared back to their initial state and reinitialized with the newly specified coordinate space dimensions."